# Debugging Laravel application and how it is running?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, xampp

I was brought in to work on and modernize a web application that is hosted on a Windows EC2 instance. There is no real source control or local development right now, all changes are done in master on the production server.

The first thing I want to do is lock down the production instance and get a local development environment up and running.

After initializing a Git repository, snapshotting the code, and pulling it locally, I used `php artisan serve` to get a local copy working. However, the local copy doesn't work, and in fact gives me the following error

```
Warning: require_once(/Users/{myUserName}/Projects/{FolderName}/{webapp_name}/public/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/{myUserName}/Projects/{FolderName}/{webapp_name}/server.php on line 21
```

Indeed, there is no `index.php` in the public folder. I have a fresh copy of `laravel/laravel` working on my machine, which does have an `index.php` in the correct place.

I've found the `index.php` in the source code, and it's in the root of the project folder. On a hunch, I went back to the EC2 instance and ran `php artisan serve --port=8123` and sure enough, it gave me the same error on the production EC2 instance.

The error is similar:

```
require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\{app_name}/public/index.php
```

Note how there is a mix of forward and backwards slashes in this path. I am unsure if this is the reason it is failing.

I am brand new to Laravel (though I have experience with PHP). Is there a different command for actually deploying a Laravel app? The app is located in the `xampp\htdocs` on the production instance.

It's been a while since I used XAMPP. I mostly just use Heroku or built in solutions from AWS/Azure for deploying web apps now so I have to re-learn the nuts and bolts.

**My question is**: how is this Laravel application running if `php artisan serve` does not work correctly on the production instance?

Comment: If `index.php` is in the project's root, someone who couldn't be bothered to configure the webserver moved it around. This is a security issue, unfortunately. This will break `php artisan serve`, as it expects it to be in `public/index.php`.

Comment: Check out the web server's configuration and look for where it's looking for index.php. Then, you should be able to see what they've done with it; and hopefully put everything (including the web config) back how it should be?

Comment: In `httpd.con`, I see the `DocumentRoot` is set to the root directory of the Laravel app. Perhaps that's why `index.php` was moved into the root directory.